# Why am I getting white spaces from this function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, whitespace

I made a function that loops through all the posts in database and echo them. But there's a slight problem. I am getting whitespace between the name (title of the post) and the content, its like two lines or so. I want reason for this and solution. Thanks.

```
function read_all_posts(){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'website';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<h1>" . $row['name'] . "</h1>" . "<br>" . $row['content'] . "<br />" . "<i>" . $row['author'] . "</i>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
}
```

Comment: trim spaces by a trim function of php

Comment: `h1` and `br` are both [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements). By default what comes after `h1` will be on the next line. Then you have a `br` right after that which does the same thing.

Comment: well `<br>` isn't a block level element, it's a linebreak tag, but same effect. Point is, remove that `<br>` tag

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<h1>" . $row['name'] . "</h1>" . "<p>" . $row['content'] . "</p>" . "<p><i>" . $row['author'] . "</i></p>";
        }
```